# Apache2 SSL setup works with Static IP but not with domain name

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu, ssl, https

So I have a digital ocean ubuntu 14.04 server that is running apache2 v2.4.7. I bought a namecheap .me domain and pointed it's URL Frame to the IP of the DO server. Everything works so far. I then signed up for a free StartSSL certificate (that's registered to the .me domain name), and added it to the server via [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps), the only thing I didnt do exactly was keep both VirtualHost 80 and 443 in the same file. I put 443 in its own default-ssl.conf file.

Now, if I go to `http://123.123.123.123` or `http://www.myexample.me` it works fine. If I go to `https://123.123.123.123` (the port 443 ssl virtualhost), it works, but it warns me because the certificate is registered to www.myexample.me, fine.

Finally, if I go to `https://www.myexample.me` it does nothing, except this in the chrome javascript console

```
GET https://www.myexample.me/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is my default-ssl.conf file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName myexample.me:443
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine on                                                                
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2                                                      
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM                
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt                           
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key                        
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem 

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When I reloaded apache after adding the certs. I was receiving this error.

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

So I added `Servername myexample.me` to the bottom of the apache2.conf file, which seemed to suppress the error.

Any guidance is appreciated. Let me know if I missed posting any information.

Comment: Sounds as if your virtual host configuration is not read when starting the apache http server.

Comment: @arkascha I'm not sure what you mean. How would I determine which config files are being loaded. I just tried it with only default-ssl in the sites-enabled folder. Nothing changed. I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, stumbled about a detail: your configuration probably is read, but this is wrong: `ServerName myexample.me:443` Take your the port number there, it should be: `ServerName myexample.me`

Comment: Hey again, thanks for the response but removing the port didnt change anything. Any other suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Does it work if you add a `ServerAlias www.myexample.me` directive?

Comment: @frasertweedale No it doesnt seem to change anything

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix it, pretty dumb mistake but if Ill post it in case anyone else makes the same one.

In namecheap's URLRedirect settings, or whichever provider you might be working with, my URL Redirect settings were set to URLFrame. But they should have been set to A (Address).

Thanks to everyone that helped.